# Saved job searches: please get back the widget with new entries counters

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

The very convenient "My saved searches" widget to the right of the job list has gone (well, moved to its own tab but still vanished as a widget.) It had a very useful feature of displaying the number of new entries in the saved searches.

Would it be possible to get back the list of saved job searches with new entries counters as a widget displayed on the main Jobs page? A lighter version with just one line per search would be just fine.

Comment: Came to say this. I can not upvote more! It was perfect. BRING IT BACK!

Answer (score 1):

The "new jobs" counter has been added into the saved job searches page.

Here is a screenshot showcasing the number of new jobs:
[image: Screenshot of saved job search counter]

Comment: Great! Thank you. The counter on the "Saved job searches" is useful. Yet, I'd personally like to see it on the main "Jobs" tab as well. Having a dashboard-style "Saved jobs with new counts" widget on the main tab would allow to see what's new from a glance right after entering the Jobs site. I'd be grateful if such a widget could be introduced (returned back).

Comment: @DmitryEgorov That is true - but there are changes being made to the main job search page that would conflict with the previous widget. Another note is that the previous widget limited the new counter to just the top 4 saved searches, whereas the new tab shows you the new job counter for all saved searches.

Comment: @ViviretSteele, Oh, I didn't know these changes were coming! Can't wait to see them! Thanks for the info.